# Adding square overlay over camera preview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a barcode scanner where the camera preview has a square overlay over it as like many of the barcode scanning apps where the outer view is lightly blurred. I am unable to find a solution for adding such overlay. I have used the AVFoundation Framework and my camera is using whole screen, I want to add the overlay in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a layer to your overlay view which is transparent at the middle and colored in remaining part by using `UIBezierPath`.

here is the example code which will draw square box from x 32 and y 32 and fill it as transparent color.

```
 UIBezierPath *overlayPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    int x = 32;
    int y = 32;
    int overlayWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 80 * 0.01;
    UIBezierPath *transparentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(x, y, overlayWidth, overlayWidth)];
    [overlayPath appendPath:transparentPath];
    [overlayPath setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];
    CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    fillLayer.path = overlayPath.CGPath;
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    [self.overlayView.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cameraOverlayView` property in your `UIImgaePickerController`. Make your custom view and add it as view

Answer (score -1):

Hi we can implement barocde functionality by using AVFoundation , In this we can use AVCaptureDevice is useful to implement that functionality, the bellow link will helpful  refer it 
http://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/

Comment: the question is how to add over lay view on top of preview. not how to achieve barcode reader

Comment: There is step by step procedure is there how to design ana how to add overlay

Comment: that guide will only display the box when qr is found .. also it is using qr code corners to get that done. the question is to have a fixed box all the time

Comment: he is designed like that, ucan design as u required by using that procedure

Comment: videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!) .  here u can add your square view as subview for the view with clear color background and design that one as u required